# Constructing Noneterministic Finite Automata (NFA) with a "not" condition

Tags: finite-automata

I have a question about some theoretical CS. Particularly, designing an NFA diagram (nondeterministic finite automata) from some conditions.

I think I understand how to construct NFA's under most simple circumstances, however, the types that I am struggling with are *not* conditions.

Here is one that has me really stumped:

Σ = { a, b, c }

Consider the language L:

L = { ω | ω ϵ Σ*, ω does not contain "cbac" }

I'd like to use the lambda-transition (λ-transition) to simplify this a bit. I am struggling with. How do I consider this condition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First construct the DFA which accepts any string that DOES contain "abaa".  Then interchange final vs non-final!  *(note: this only works with a DFA, not an NFA)*  The rest you have already figured out.

Comment: It does seem that this would certainly be the case with DFA. In fact, making a DFA for this problem doesn't seem too challenging, but making reasonably-sized NFA does seem to be. This is odd because you'd certainly think that NFA's would be easier to construct than DFA's (because of the additional flexibility λ-transition give you). Any idea how to approach NFA construction here?

Comment: @RonGermano, a DFA *is* an NFA, it just doesn't make use of the extra flexibility of nondeterminism.